# How to create a mask in svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I have tried put two svg element to create a hollow mask. And I want to create the effect like clip-path inset, but the result doesn't work. How can I solve this? Or are there any ways to achieve same effect?

https://codepen.io/penny289/pen/Exvaeaq?editors=1000

```css
body{margin:0}
.aurora{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.move1,.move2,.move3{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius:2%;
  z-index:-2;
}

.move1{
  box-shadow: 0 0 35vmax 35vmax #0D8BD9;
  
}
.move2{
  box-shadow: 0 0 35vmax 35vmax #0ff;
  
}
.move3{
  box-shadow: 0 0 35vmax 35vmax #94D7F2;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="aurora">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <mask id="mask1">
      <path fill="black" d="M51,-41.9C63.3,-25.1,68.8,-4.1,65.3,16.4C61.8,37,49.5,57,33.3,62C17.1,67.1,-2.8,57.2,-24.3,47.8C-45.8,38.5,-68.9,29.7,-74.5,14.3C-80.2,-1.1,-68.5,-23.2,-53.2,-40.7C-37.9,-58.1,-19,-70.8,0.2,-70.9C19.3,-71.1,38.6,-58.6,51,-41.9Z" />
    </mask>
    <rect width="100vw" height="100vh" fill="white" mask="url(#mask1)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <div class="move1"></div>
  <div class="move2"></div>
  <div class="move3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand you. If you need to cut a hole in the masked rect you need a mask with  a white rectangle <rect width="200" height="200" fill="white"/> followed by the black filled path.
Also I wouldn't use  `width="100vw" height="100vh"`. I would use `width="200" height="200"` since this will cover all the svg element

Comment: @enxaneta yes, I want to cut a hole on the rect. But i don’t understand that it work on clip-path rather on mask.

Comment: In a mask you will see what apears under the white zone and cut off whatever falls under the black. To cut a hole (as I've commented before) you need a white rectangle under the black path

Comment: You means set fill in color white and black? Or I need to change the position of rect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mask is just masking off everything by default - the same as creating a mask with a black rectangle that is 100% in height and width. You path has a black fill, so black+black is still a 100% black mask.

I added a white rectangle in the mask, so that you can see the difference between masking with black/white.

And then your path was a bit off to the left/top, so I did a translate to place it inside the SVG viewbox.

```css
body{margin:0}
.aurora{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.move1,.move2,.move3{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius:2%;
  z-index:-2;
}

.move1{
  box-shadow: 0 0 35vmax 35vmax #0D8BD9;
  
}
.move2{
  box-shadow: 0 0 35vmax 35vmax #0ff;
  
}
.move3{
  box-shadow: 0 0 35vmax 35vmax #94D7F2;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="aurora">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <mask id="mask1">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <path transform="translate(90 80)" fill="black" d="M51,-41.9C63.3,-25.1,68.8,-4.1,65.3,16.4C61.8,37,49.5,57,33.3,62C17.1,67.1,-2.8,57.2,-24.3,47.8C-45.8,38.5,-68.9,29.7,-74.5,14.3C-80.2,-1.1,-68.5,-23.2,-53.2,-40.7C-37.9,-58.1,-19,-70.8,0.2,-70.9C19.3,-71.1,38.6,-58.6,51,-41.9Z" />
    </mask>
    <rect width="100vw" height="100vh" fill="white" mask="url(#mask1)"></rect>
  </svg>
  <div class="move1"></div>
  <div class="move2"></div>
  <div class="move3"></div>
</div>
```